# Remove extra spaces in the list from a function - python

Tags: python, nltk

Trying to remove words that are in the stopwords list. The final list should contain only the words which are not in the stopwords list. But my code returns with empty spaces in place of stopwords along with non-stop words as shown below

> ['','organizing','','','','',team]

Comment: What is words_tokenize() ? is it word_tokenize() from nltk?

Comment: Nope. It is customized function thats splits the tokens in a sentence and returns a list of tokens. I want to keep only the non-stopwords in the list

Comment: Where is your stop word list. I think it should be inside of the function or you should provide it as an argument. If not your function can be broke in future changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you're doing here which make it a bit confusing - your function has the same name as your list of stopwords, for example, which is less than ideal.

Essentially though, I think you're overcomplicating it, and there are useful features of the language - such as the `.join()` string method - which can help you out here.

Below is an example function that removes stopwords from a sentence, when provided with the sentence and a list of stopwords.

```py
def remove_stopwords(sentence, stopwords):
    
    # Split the sentence into a list of words
    words = sentence.split(",")

    # Holder for words to keep
    final_words = []
    
    # Loop through all the words
    for word in words:
        
        # Only keep the words that aren't in stopwords
        if word not in stopwords:
            
            # Add valid words to the holder
            final_words.append(word)
            
    # Join the words together into a string and return it
    return " ".join(final_words)
```

It's not a perfect function - it can be optimised in several ways, and it's using a very crude tokeniser (`.split()`); I didn't want to add in a bunch of complexities that would obscure the core ideas. Hopefully you should be able to add your custom functions etc. in the necessary places.

In brief, the function does the following:

1. Splits a sentence into a list of words
2. Loops through the words, checking if each one is in the `stopwords` list
3. Adds words not in `stopwords` into a new list
4. Joins the new list into a string using `.join()`